# Does Beatrice know about Return By Death?

Tags: re-zero

During episode 7, Beatrice was contracted to protect Subaru. When she is with him on the cliff she suggests he "die where she can't see him" so she won't "have bad dreams," about it. Maybe she was being sarcastic, referring to the fact that he should die, suggesting Rem's death was his fault? I'm not sure if it was sarcastic, but it seemed to me like she was suggesting he kill himself to Return By Death? It sounded like she was conveying that he wasted his chance to explain himself to Ram, this time, but could kill himself and try again? Ah, I don't know... She says "I'll help you escape this domain"... What was she foreshadowing here? Does she know?

Comment: I'd say yeah, beatrice is kind of an enigma. Not only does her memory not get wiped when Subaru uses return by death. But she aims solely to keep out of his affairs. In spite of making a contract with him and then never bringing it up again. Also when Rem died due to the curse don't you find it odd that she was able to hold the master of the house at bay long enough for him to get away? Like how powerful is she?

Answer (score 2):

It is because she is somewhat attracted to him (not in romantic means of course). Beatrice to some degree cares about him, otherwise, she would not agree to be in contract with him. That is why she said, "I you want to die, die at a place I cannot see. I don't want to have nightmare." Implicitly she is saying, "Don't let me see you die. I care about you, so if you die in front of me, I'll have nightmare about it."

That is why, rather than knowing about Return by Death, it is more like she cares about him and don't want him to die.

Answer (score 0):

She was confused when Subaru seemed to show little fear or panic when hearing about his impending demise by the Wolgarms' curses. She really does seem to let on that she knows at times. But I am confident she does not. When she sent him away after the unseen hand crushed Emilia's heart, she knew that Puck would soon go on a rampage and end his life.